# Find an expression whose derivative is multiplicatively separable?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, closed-form

Is there an example of an expression using $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ (perhaps composed with other elementary functions) whose derivative can be factorized into multiplicatively separable expressions, one containing $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$, and the other containing $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$?

In other words, I'm looking for an example of a function $\Psi$ such that
$$\left[\Psi(f(x), g(x))\right]' = \phi(f(x), f'(x)) \cdot \varphi(g(x), g'(x)).$$

For instance, if one considers
\begin{align}
\Psi &= f(x)\exp(g(x))\\
\Rightarrow \Psi' &= [f'(x) + f(x)g'(x)]\exp(g(x))
\end{align}
this seems close, but doesn't work because the $g'(x)$ cannot be factored out of the square-bracketed expression.

edit: I'm trying to find a non-trivial example of $\Psi$, some formulation of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that results in a separable derivative with respect to a single variable, $x$.

Comment: There is at least one family of trivial solutions to this, namely the one where the partial of $Psi(x,y)$ with respect to either $x$ or $y$ is always $0$. Examples in this family include of course the functions $\Psi(x,y)=x$ and $\Psi(x,y)=y$ There may be other such families. It would be helpful if you could give more specific criteria for the types of solutions you want so as to avoid these kinds of solutions.

Comment: Thanks, edited the post. Hopefully that clarifies it a bit; I'm hoping to find a non-trivial solution that formulates $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in such a way that the derivative has this separable property.

Comment: I don't think such a function exists. No matter what you do this functional will be of the form $A[f,g]f'+B[f,g]g'$ making only trivial solutions possible.